# Azure CloudBlockBlob. Cannot find the blob when DownloadToStream. Uri seems repeated?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Azure Development Blob Storage..

Uploading the blob works perfectly, and i can double-click the image uploaded in the visual studio blob container view and open the picture...

But if you look at this picture :

[image]

...there is something wrong with the Uri ?

Here is the code i'm using :

```
public MemoryStream DownloadBlob(int id)
    {
        Photo photo = PhotoServices.GetPhotoById(id);
        var cloudBlobContainer = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(CurrentBlobContainerName);
        var blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(photo.BlobUrl);
        var memorystream = new MemoryStream();

// THIS LINE GIVES BLOB NOT FOUND EXCEPTION
        blob.DownloadToStream(memorystream);

       memorystream.Position = 0;
       return memorystream;
```

Here is how i store the blobs :

```
public CloudBlockBlob UploadBlob(Stream fileStream, string fileName)
    {
        var blobName = Guid.NewGuid() + fileName;
        var blockBlob = GetContainer().GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

        blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
        return blockBlob;
    }
```

Here is how i get the blob :

```
public MemoryStream DownloadBlob(int id)
    {
        Photo photo = PhotoServices.GetPhotoById(id);
        var cloudBlobContainer = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(CurrentBlobContainerName);
        var blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(photo.BlobUrl);
        var memorystream = new MemoryStream();
        memorystream.Position = 0;
        blob.DownloadToStream(memorystream);
        return memorystream;
    }
```

Here is how the blob look like in the dev. storage (it's clickable and viewable from there)

```
    Name : bla-bla-bla.jpg
    Content Type : application/octet-stream
    URL : http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/userid1/bla-bla-bla.jpg
```

So... what should i change in the way i get the picture to get the normal URL ?

Soo.. is there any obvious thing's i'm doing wrong here ?

here is the complete NET Response msg :

```
{"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.","ExceptionType":"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException","StackTrace":"   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.DownloadRangeToStream(Stream target, Nullable`1 offset, Nullable`1 length, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStream(Stream target, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)\r\n   at ServiceLibrary.Services.StorageServices.DownloadBlob(Int32 id) in c:\\PhotoApp\\ServiceLibrary\\Services\\StorageServices.cs:line 116\r\n   at PhotoWebApp.Controllers.PhotoSubmitController.GetPhotoById(Int32 id) in c:\\PhotoApp\\PhotoWebApp\\Controllers\\PhotoSubmitController.cs:line 28\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"$id":"2","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.WebException","StackTrace":"   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)"}}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your method using the debugger? What values do you see for the *photo.BlobUrl* ? Your blob code looks correct, not sure about your *PhotoServices.GetPhotoById(id)* though -- that may be the culprit. You must have done something to the filename when uploading the blob. Try removing it and uploading a blob manually (not in code) and then using that URI directly in your code, temporarily eliminating the code to get the photo. You can also try passing *GetContainerReference* a specific container name for troubleshooting purposes as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that you are storing blob's absolute URL in `BlobUrl` property in your application. Based on the documentation for [`CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj682596.aspx), it should be **`name of the blob`**. So in your case, it should be just the name of the image file.

If you look closely at the screenshot you shared especially blob's URI property, you will notice the problem. Blob's Uri property is `http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/userid1/http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/userid1/85066...mongo.jpg` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/userid1/85066...mongo.jpg`.

Comment: I have updated the question a bit Gaurav :) Hmm.. Do you know what code changes should be done to make it right ?

Comment: Which version of storage client library are you using?

Comment: 4.1.0 it seems :) Just updated it the other day... 
BUT.. i did a little tweak here, and used the Name as you said, instead of the Uri and it seems to work out :) Weird.. cause we did exactly as the previous example in an earlier project and that worked out like a charm.. *hmm..*

Comment: There have been some changes in the way this method works between previous versions of library and the new version. It could be because of that.

Comment: Gaurav's comment is correct. This is a known change. You can see a full [breaking changes log](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/BreakingChanges.txt) in the GitHub repository.

Comment: This line is useful - "It seems that you are storing blob's absolute URL in BlobUrl property in your application. Based on the documentation for CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference, it should be name of the blob. "